# Performance implications when hiding a DIV by rendering it offscreen

Tags: html, performance, show-hide

What are the performance implications of hiding a complex portion of an HTML document within an offscreen DIV like:

```
<div style="position:absolute;top:-10000px;left:-10000px;">
  Lots of HTML here...
</div>
```

as compared to using "display: none" or "visiblity: hidden" ?

Is there a performance/memory-usage penalty? How bad is it?
Can this be advisable if the targets are mobile browsers (iPhone/Android)?

Comment: Browsers are smart enough not to render stuff that's off screen. I doubt it makes any difference.

Comment: @Tim I'm not so sure about that. For example, geometry must still be computed when using "visibility: hidden" while this is not the case with "display: none". For off screen rendering I just don't know and that's why I'm asking :)

Comment: I just thought you might be implying that browsers render the offscreen stuff into a back buffer which I'm sure they don't. You could be right that geometry calculations make some difference.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the browser. [Here](http://www.phpied.com/rendering-repaint-reflowrelayout-restyle/) is good article about rendering, reflow repaint in browsers. So theoretically it should be not rendered when something changed on the side as all absolute positioned elements will not rerendered when something changed in there parent elements. So it should perform better then display:none which will be [rerendered in IE](http://www.phpied.com/the-new-game-show-will-it-reflow/) for example. But you have still a lot of DOM elements in browser memory. So maybe its better to put the elements out of the DOM and add them again later.

Answer (score 1):

Performance-wise you're best to build up your HTML as a string as insert it into the DOM in one go. DOM changes trigger redraws, so the fewer DOM changes the better.

Comment: OP didn't say anything about Javascript and the DOM. He's talking about HTML and CSS only.